# Apply fastifySession Middleware in nest js - Using the MiddlewareConsumer in the AppModule

Tags: typescript, nestjs, fastify, nestjs-fastify, fastify-cookie

I have a `Nestjs` app with `Fastify`. I want to apply the `fastifySession` middleware using the `MiddlewareConsumer`. Usually, it works like below:

```
configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(
        fastifySession,
      )
      .forRoutes({
        path: '*',
        method: RequestMethod.ALL,
      });
  }
}
```

The problem is that `fastifySession` needs an `options` object. In a regular app, it is called using the `register` method like below:

```
app.register(fastifySession, {
   secret: '',
   cookie: {
     secure: false,
     domain: 'localhost',
   },
  store: new SessionStore(new SessionService()),
});
```

I don't want to use the `register` method in `main.ts` as I want to make use of the `Nestjs dependency injection`. So, I need to apply the middleware in the AppModule. Is there a way to do this?

**UPDATE**

I thought I can develop a Nestjs middleware to register the fastify plugins that I need.

I created this middleware:

```
@Injectable()
class FastifySession implements NestMiddleware {
  private options;
  private fastifyPassport;

  constructor(
    private adapterHost: HttpAdapterHost,
    private sessionStore: SessionStore,
    private userService: UserService,
  ) {
    this.fastifyPassport = new Authenticator();

    this.options = {
      cookie: {
        secure: false,
        maxAge: 50000,
        path: '/',
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: false,
        domain: 'localhost',
      },
      store: this.sessionStore,
    };
  }

  use(req: any, res: any, next: (error?: any) => void) {
    const httpAdapter = this.adapterHost.httpAdapter;
    const instance = httpAdapter.getInstance();

    instance.register(fastifyCookie);
    instance.register(fastifySession, this.options);

    instance.register(this.fastifyPassport.initialize());
    instance.register(this.fastifyPassport.secureSession());

    this.fastifyPassport.registerUserSerializer(async (user: User, request) => {
      console.log(user.id);
      return user.id;
    });

    this.fastifyPassport.registerUserDeserializer(async (id, request) => {
      const user = await this.userService.getUser(+id);
      console.log('user ', user);
      return user;
    });

    next();
  }
}
```

I added the middleware to my AppModule

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  constructor() {
  }

  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(FastifySession)
      .forRoutes({
        path: '*',
        method: RequestMethod.ALL,
      });
  }
}
```

**But** I get his error

```
ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Root plugin has already booted
AvvioError: Root plugin has already booted
```

I came across this GitHub Issue

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1462

As stated in the GitHub issue, I think It is not possible to register Fastify plugins outside main.ts.

I will appreciate anyone helping me! or at least guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To register a plugin inside a module, I would use `onModuleInit` and a module that injects the `HttpAdapterHost`. Something like this:

```js
@Module(moduleMetadata)
export class AppModule implements OnMoudleInit {
  constructor(private readonly httpAdapterHost: HttpAdapterHost) {}

  async onModuleInit() {
    const adapterInstance = this.httpAdapterHost.httpAdapter.getInstance();
    await adapterInstance.register(fastifySession, fastifySessionOptions)
  }
}
```

This way, the adapter registers the middleware at application startup and you don't accidentally end up registering it multiple times on each route call (`use` will be called on each matching route and you end up calling `instance.register()` a lot with the current code in the question)

Comment: Thank you, Jay. I have used OnMoudleInit and It is working as expected Thank you